# Pivot unknown Column content

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have the following data **but I don't know the content of the table before**

```
courses table
-------------
id  | name
-------------
7   | math
99  | geology
4   | ethics
5   | sports
33  | english
29  | math boot camp
```

I need the output as

```
course1_id | course1_name | course2_id | course2_name | course3_id | course3_name
         7 | math         |         99 |      geology |          4 |       ethics
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0b4c/7)

I tried

```
select case when id = 7 then id end as course1_id, 
       case when id = 7 then name end as course1_name
from courses
```

but that returns multiple rows instead of one and since I don't know the `id` I can't use that approach. Any ideas?

Comment: what do mean by this _but I don't know the content of the table before_

Comment: The `id`s can be anything and I don't know the names of the possible courses. Could be anything too.

Comment: Just seen the edit, what is the order of courses based on? i.e. Why is geology course 2, and ethics course 3?

Comment: @GarethD: The order is irrelevant. I want to output all courses. I just reduced the example output to 3 to avoid scrolling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL You would need is:

```
SELECT  Course1_ID = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN ID END),
        Course1_Name = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Name END),
        Course2_ID = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN ID END),
        Course2_Name = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN Name END),
        Course3_ID = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN ID END),
        Course3_Name = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN Name END)
FROM    (   SELECT  ID, 
                    Name, 
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)
            FROM    Courses
        ) C;
```

But with unkown content you would need to generate this dynamically:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + 
                            STUFF(( SELECT  ',Course' + RowNum + '_ID = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + RowNum + ' THEN ID END)
                                            ,Course' + RowNum + '_Name = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + RowNum + ' THEN Name END)'
                                    FROM    (   SELECT  RowNum = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS VARCHAR(10))
                                                FROM    Courses
                                            ) c
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') + 
                                ' FROM (    SELECT  ID, 
                                                    Name, 
                                                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)
                                            FROM    Courses
                                        ) C;'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a38d/1)**

---

Another way to achieve the same result is:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT   @SQL = @SQL + 
                    ',Course' + RowNum + '_ID = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + RowNum + ' THEN ID END)
                    ,Course' + RowNum + '_Name = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + RowNum + ' THEN Name END)'
FROM    (   SELECT  RowNum = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS VARCHAR(10))
            FROM    Courses
        ) c;

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + STUFF(@SQL, 1, 1, '') + '
            FROM (  SELECT  ID, 
                            Name, 
                            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)
                    FROM    Courses
                ) c;';

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

*This removes the expensive XML extensions to concatenate rows into columns*

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0b4c/12)**

If the order of courses is relevant at all you can just change the order by clause in the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

Answer (score 0):

i would use a pivot. since you have no information as to the length of the table, it will have to be dynamic:

```
declare @count int;
declare @i int;
declare @p varchar(max) = '';
declare @s varchar(max) = '';

select @count = COUNT(*) from courses;

set @i = 1;
while @i <= @count
begin
  set @p = @p + ', [course'+convert(varchar,@i)+'_id], [course'+convert(varchar,@i)+'_name]';
  set @i = @i+1;
end


set @p = substring (@p,3,len(@p)-2);

set @s = 'select '+@p+'
       from
( select ''course''+convert(varchar,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by convert(int,id)))+''_id'' as rn 
       , courses.id as c
    from courses
   union all
  select ''course''+convert(varchar,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by convert(int,id)))+''_name'' as rn 
       , courses.name as c
    from courses ) as sourcetable
  pivot ( 
    max(c)
    for rn in ('+@p+')
    )  as pivottable';

execute(@s);
```