# Pivoting pivoted table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following query:\

```
SELECT *

FROM   (SELECT 1 CntCol, CONVERT(CHAR(3), [data out (no val#vuoto)], 0) month, 
               ( [gruppi min (gg flusso/decorrenza-->out)] ) 
        FROM   dbpratiche 
        WHERE  compagnia = 'GENERALI INA ASSITALIA' 
               AND stato = 'OUT ATTIVATA' 
               AND [data out (no val#vuoto)] > '01-01-2012') TLB 
       PIVOT ( Count(CntCol) 
             FOR tlb.month IN([nov], 
                              [dec], 
                              [jan], 
                              [feb], 
                              [mar], 
                              [apr],
                              [May],
                              [jun],
                              [jul],
                              [aug],
                              [sep],
                              [oct] ) )PVT
```

This pivote query produces following result:

[image]

I want to again pivote this table to get the result as:

```
Months  <=06   <=8  <=10   >10

Jan     0       1    1      6

Feb     8       5    4      2

Mar     9       7    6      2
```

Please help.

Comment: As much as I would like to help you, this should be easy for you. You already duplicated the previous answer, but go and read up on Pivot. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878189/pivoting-a-column-and-showing-data-according-to-count/20879567?noredirect=1#comment31334377_20879567). That is how I helped you in the first place. I gave you a link, read how it works? We are not here to do the work for you. I've done that in your first post. Play a little, and figure it out.

Comment: @Jaques sir thanx for being tough on me, i solved it myself,, i strongly needed that bitter medicine which you provided me through comment

Comment: I'm glad. The reason being, if I helped you again, you would come back again next time. Now you know how to fish, and you will be able to do it yourself next time. Good for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM   (SELECT 1 CntCol, CONVERT(CHAR(3), [data out (no val#vuoto)], 0) month, 
           ( [gruppi min (gg flusso/decorrenza-->out)] ) 
       FROM   dbpratiche 
       WHERE  compagnia = 'GENERALI INA ASSITALIA' 
           AND stato = 'OUT ATTIVATA' 
           AND [data out (no val#vuoto)] > '01-01-2012') TLB 
   PIVOT ( Count(CntCol) 
         FOR tlb.[gruppi min (gg flusso/decorrenza-->out)] IN
                         ([<=06], 
                          [<=08], 
                          [<=10], 
                          [>10] ) )PVT
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself through:

```
select * from
(
  SELECT 1 CntCol, CONVERT(CHAR(3), [data out (no val#vuoto)], 0) month, 
               ( [gruppi min (gg flusso/decorrenza-->out)] ) 
        FROM   dbpratiche 
        WHERE  compagnia = 'GENERALI INA ASSITALIA' 
               AND stato = 'OUT ATTIVATA' 
               AND [data out (no val#vuoto)] > '01-01-2012'
) T
pivot
(
  count(cntcol)
  for [gruppi min (gg flusso/decorrenza-->out)]
  in([>10],[<=10],[<=06],[<=08])

)P
```

Answer (score 1):

what you seem to be wanting is to have the pivot the other way round. i suggest you try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 1 CntCol, CONVERT(CHAR(3), [data out (no val#vuoto)], 0) month, 
               ( [gruppi min (gg flusso/decorrenza-->out)] as gg) 
        FROM   dbpratiche 
        WHERE  compagnia = 'GENERALI INA ASSITALIA' 
               AND stato = 'OUT ATTIVATA' 
               AND [data out (no val#vuoto)] > '01-01-2012') TLB 
       PIVOT ( Count(CntCol) 
             FOR tlb.gg IN([<=06], 
                              [<=08], 
                              [<=10], 
                              [>10]
                              ) )PVT
```

or in case you have more than the mentioned values in your columns, look at dynamic sql like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212611/pivot-unknown-column-content/20213582)